# ido in Yasnippet save new snippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet, ido

I want to save a new snippet. Emacs24 asks me for the filename, but ido does not work in the minibuffer. Is that a known bug, or a bug in my configuration.

#### How to reproduce:

```
$ emacs /tmp/test.tex
```

Menu: YSSnippet/New Snippet

I create a small snippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: int
# key: int
# --
\int_{$1}^{$2} $3 \diff\,$4
```

now i want to save it and press `C-x C-s`
minibuffer says 
`File to save in: /tmp/`
I would expect the features of `ido` in this minibuffer it should look like

```
Write file: /tmp/{test.tex| foo.tex | bar.tex | ...}
```

But it does not work. My configuration is online on [github](https://github.com/jonasstein/emacs-config)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your problem? Currently it is hard to understand exactly when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to customize `ido-everywhere`?

Comment: @Cthulhu: Have you tried it?  I'm not 100% sure it does what the user wants, but I think there's a good chance it does.

Comment: Ok. I just thought it looked like a comment :) sorry